# CAKEPHP form retrieval

Tags: javascript, php, forms, cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I'm pretty new to CAKEPHP and PHP in general.

What I am trying to do is get an Id from a row in the database ('which I already have'), then pass that from on page to another on a submit.

Here is page 1:

(This form is generated by javascript btw)

```
<form action="spots/reserve" method="post" name="formToPass">
 <input type="hidden" name="spotId" id="spotId" value="<?php echo Spot[i]['id']?>">
</form>
```

Now I need to get that ID on the reserve page so that I can go into the DB and get the row with that Id and display the data.  When I submit what I currently have I do get ?spotId=# at the end of my url.  Does that mean it is working and I am just missing something?

Any help would be appreciated.  Thank you.

*** UPDATE ***

I changed the method from post to get and I am now able to echo that id out on the reserve page.  Before with the post method I was getting Notice of undefined variable.

Comment: Yes, but I'm still curious as to why I had to use GET instead of POST?

Comment: Please check my answer. If it's useful, set the answer as accepted or vote it up. Otherwise just write what's missing in the answer or what are the problems you're dealing with now and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to submit your form using POST method, form data in the controller should be accessible via *$this->request->data* property. So if your field's id is spotId, you should be able to access it in the controller via:

```
$spotId = $this->request->data['spotId'];
```

You can also check what data is submitted in your form by typing:

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

Comment: I'm still new to stackoverflow and need a 15 rep to upvote, but this worked and helped me understand what my issue was.